# Backbone.js versus Express versus Ext JS ...and JSPP?

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-framework

What are the pros and cons of Backbone.js, Express, Ext JS, and JSPP??

Comment: The question is pointless, just like the answer states. There's no relevant connection between the libraries mentioned above.

Comment: no connection, really? nice question Desai, it made someone write a good answer.

Answer (score 22):

There all very different.

backbone.js is a client-side MVC framework.

JSPP is a means you can write inline server-side code (like PHP or ASP) for nodejs

Express is a node.js specific server-side framework for web development.

Ext JS is a framework for making web applications and widgets.

There all *very* different. There isn't any point in a direct comparison without you telling us what you want to use them for.

To vaguely answer your question. IMHO I would say using backbone.js on the client and on nodejs is great for MVC centric design.

Express is a great layer of abstraction on nodejs because it beats writing the code yourself. Use it to serve content to your clients.

Ext JS is not free.

JSPP looks like ASP/PHP!

Comment: I didn't realize backbone was client-side, nor that Ext JS isn't free, thank you for the response.

Comment: @DesaiShukla EXT JS is also client side. They can be used with nodejs but thats very different the a natively designed nodejs framework.